# Atlassian Forge Jira Dashboard Gadget - No "entryPoint" for edit mode

Tags: jira, dashboard

I am working on a Custom UI Dashboard Gadget using the forge documentation [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/manifest-reference/modules/jira-dashboard-gadget). The documentation refers to the `context.extension.entryPoint`. I can retrieve and see the `context`, and `context.extension` in the values returned by `view.getContext()` but there is no `entryPoint` key in the returned object.

How should I determine whether the dashboard is in edit mode so that I can configure my gadget?

Relevant code is.

```
import { view } from '@forge/bridge';

const context = await view.getContext()
console.info(JSON.stringify(context))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Atlassian documentation says "With a Custom UI, you can define the same resource for viewing and editing your dashboard gadget" and then goes on to describe the code I posted above for retrieving the context.  I have been unable to use the same component for configuring the dashboard because there is no 'edit' information in the context.  The only solution I have managed to find is to create a separate component for configuring the dashboard and thus specifying the below manifest, which points at a separate component for editing.

```
jira:dashboardGadget:
    ...
      resource: dashboard-quality
      resolver:
        function: resolver
      edit:
        resource: dashboard-quality-edit
```

This seems to work and it isn't much additional effort, so I am going to accept this as an answer to my own Q, even though it doesn't really solve it based on my original intent.